# Python code not working. Trying to compute two fibonacci numbers and find greatest common factor

Tags: python, fibonacci

Can someone please help with this code. I'm attempting to write the simplest program possible that reads in 2 numbers (m,n), then computes the nth fibonacci number and the mth fibonacci number and then finds the greatest common factor of the two inputted numbers. This is what I have so far. I'm new to Python, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
def compute():
    m, n = -1, -1
    while m<0: m = int(input(“Please enter a positive number for m: “))
    while n<0: m = int(input(“Please enter a positive number for n: “))
    a, b = 1,1
    for i in (‘temp’, a+b), 
             (‘a’, b), 
             (‘b’, temp),
             (‘mth’, b if i==m)
             (‘nth’, b if i==m)
    for i in range(2, n+1)),:pass
    maxlen=0)
return max(i for i in range(1, nth+1) if not mth%i and not nth%i)
```

Comment: Break this into pieces. Do you know how to compute Fibonacci numbers? Do you know how to compute GCDs? Write functions for each piece, and then use those functions to perform your task.

Comment: Consider using a function to return the Fibonacci number of a particular index and one to find the greatest common denominator of two given numbers.  Test the two functions independently with known value, and only when you're sure they work, tie them together in your compute function.  If you build your code with known good components, you will have an easier time debugging their combination.

Comment: You never specified the way in which your "Python code not working," so how about those smart quotes there? SO's syntax highlighting will show you that those aren't working properly. There are also several syntax errors that are nowhere close to valid Python.

Comment: Is this homework? There was someone else asking [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442200/python-fibonacci-number/34442379) a few hours ago, where you incidentally borrowed your code from. You haven't exactly showed understanding of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, when it comes to Python, the simplest answer might be either the smallest piece of code or the code that's easiest to understand (and sometimes both things are the same). Since you're starting with Python, I think the easiest to understand is the best way to approach, but I reckon that qwertyboys's answer might be also correct (and more advanced).

This is how I would do (I agree with user2357112's comment on splitting the problem into two parts):

```
first_num = int(input("Enter the first positive number: "))
second_num = int(input("Enter the second positive number: "))

fib_a, fib_b = 1, 1
fib_sequence = [1, 1]

for i in range (first_num + second_num):
    temp = fib_a + fib_b    
    fib_a = fib_b
    fib_b = temp
    fib_sequence.append(temp)
    
from fractions import gcd

print("Fibonacci sequence's #%s: %s" % (first_num, fib_sequence[first_num - 1]))
print("Fibonacci sequence's #%s: %s" % (second_num, fib_sequence[second_num - 1]))
print("Their Greatest Common Divisor is: %s" % gcd(fib_sequence[first_num - 1], fib_sequence[second_num - 1]))
```

I first created a Fibonacci's list that's long enough to fit both indexes, and then picked the ones I wanted. An output example would be:

> Enter the first positive number: 3
>
> Enter the second positive number: 6
>
> Fibonacci sequence's #3: 2
>
> Fibonacci sequence's #6: 8
>
> Their Greatest Common Divisor is: 2

Although it's not the most elegant solution (yes, there is recursion and the likes), I've tried to keep it clear on what's happening, hope it helps. Remember that readability is a very important part of coding (specially on Python) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gcd from fractions for the greatest common divisor, and defining a non recursive fibonacci calculator is pretty simple. Now you just need to bring them in together:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from math import sqrt
from fractions import gcd
from sys import argv

def fib(n):
    return int(((1+sqrt(5))**n-(1-sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*sqrt(5)))

fib1, fib2 = [fib(int(arg)) for arg in argv[1:3]]
fibs_gcd = gcd(fib1, fib2)

print("greatest common divisor of {} and {} fibonacci numbers ({} and {}) is {}".format(
    argv[1], argv[2], fib1, fib2, fibs_gcd))
```

Save to file and run it with `python <file name> <first num> <second num>`.

Comment: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: May I ask why you saved a `lambda` instead of just using `def`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - there was no special reason, but then again, there was also no reason to use `def` instead of `lambda` :)

Comment: [Yes, there is.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - changed the code per your explanation. Thanks.